# How to simply the python code in getting items from tuples?

Tags: python

How to write a loop to get the items from tuples?

The tuples are:

```
order = (1, 0, 1)
seasonal_order = (0, 1, 1, 12)
```

The codes I wrote:

```
d = (bestdpq['order'])[0]

p = (bestdpq['order'])[1]

q = (bestdpq['order'])[2]

sd = (bestdpq['seasonal_order'])[0]

sp = (bestdpq['seasonal_order'])[1]

sq = (bestdpq['seasonal_order'])[2]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use unpacking (and better variable names than `d`, `p` and `q`)

```
d, p, q = bestdpq['order']
```

In case of `bestdpq['seasonal_order']` where you have 4 elements in the tuple but want the first 3 you can use `_` which is the convention for unused/ignored variables (and won't trigger linters):

```
sd, sp, sq, _ = bestdpq['seasonal_order']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
order = (1, 0, 1)
for e in order:
    print(e)
```

Here i am printing each of the elements of the tuple. You could do whatever action you wish. For example, you could decide to find cumulative sum by adding the elements together as you loop.